# Not Scrolling elements inside HTML pages in phonegap in Android version

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, android-webview

I am working on phonegap application.

In, iPhone version, we can stop bouncing by "UIWebViewBounce" set to NO.

So how can I stop bouncing in Android version for web-view.

Because In Android version, its bouncing and consider as scrolling. So I can't scroll elements which are inside scrollbar in html pages.

Any solution For activate scrolling of scrollbars and stop bouncing main screen.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you cant get the normal html scroll behavior when trying to create a app using phonegap on android.
you cant get the overflow:scroll effect for any of the html elements in android webview.
you'll need to make use of third party libraries such as  [jquerymobile,](http://jquerymobile.com/)   [iscroll4,](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) etcfor getting the native look and feel.
or also you can construct your own logic

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example that will show the scroll bar. It will help you.

```
  public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        // Display vertical scrollbar and hide horizontal scrollBar
        super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // set scrollbar style
        super.appView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    }

 }
```

Comment: NejiHyuga  okay. i understand he is looking for the scroll bar. So for scrolling inside the element iScroll is usefull.

Comment: Thanks both od you. But I think I have to implement iScroll for html elements.